# Normal distribution with the minimum values in Matlab

Tags: matlab, normal-distribution

I tried to generate 1000 the random values in normal distribution by the normrnd function.

```
 A = normrnd(4,1,[1000 1]);
```

I would like to set the minimum value is 2. However, that function just can define the mean and sd. How can I set the minimum value is 2 ?

Comment: You can't. It wouldn't be a normal distribution anymore

Comment: @LuisMendo and if he adds `min(A(:))+2` to `A`? Arent they technically Gaussian distributed still? Just offseted? Honest question.

Comment: @AnderBiguri No, it wouldn't be a Gaussian. For example, in a Gaussian distribution there is a non-zero probability of getting _any_ value, however small. That would no longer be the case with this procedure, as values below 2 would have probability strictly 0. You can add a _constant_ offset to a Gaussian and it remains Gaussian; but in general you can't add an offset _that depends on the generated values_, because that alters the distribution

Comment: You might want to look up the gamma distribution. It probably fits your purposes better.

Comment: Dear all, if I set the min=2 and max=6 in this case. Will that be the normal distribution ? Please tell me how to set that condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Gaussian or normally distributed numbers are in a bell curve, with the tails tailing off to infinity. What you can do is "censor" them by eliminating every number beyond a cut-off.

Comment: Censoring makes the distribution non-Gaussian

Answer (score 0):

Since you choose mean = 4 and sigma = 1, you will end up ~95% elements of A fall within range [2,6]. The number of elements whose values smaller than 2 is about 2.5%. If you consider this figure is small, you can wrap these elements to a minimum value. For example:

```
 A = normrnd(4,1,[1000 1]);
```

[image: A_before]

```
A(A < 2) = A(A<2) + 2 - min(A(A<2))
```

[image: A_after]

Of course, it is technically not gaussian distribution. However if you have total control of mean and sigma, you can get a "more gaussian like" distribution by adding an offset to A:

```
A = A + 2 - min(A)
```

Comment: thanks . It is not the normal distribution in this case. I am thinking about setting the min=2 and max = 6 . Will that be the normal distribution in this case ? If it is convenient, could you please tell me how to set that condition ?

Comment: a strictly normal distribution have `min = -Inf` and `max = +Inf`. If you set `min=2` and/or `max=6`, it is no longer normal distribution, but close enough to satisfy most of your applications.

Answer (score 0):

*Note: This assumes you can have an arbitrarily set standard deviation, which may not be the case*

As others have said, you cannot specify a lower bound for a true Gaussian. However, you can generate a Gaussian and estimate `1-p` percent of values to be above and then ignore `p` percent of values (which will fall outside your cutoff).

For example, in the following code, I am generating a Gaussian where 95% of data-points fall above 2. Then I am removing all points below 2, knowing that 5% of data will be removed.

This is a **solution** because setting as p gets closer to zero, your chances of getting uncensored sample data that follows your Gaussian curve and is entirely above your cutoff goes to 100% (Really it's defined by the `p/n` ratio, but if `n` is fixed this is true).

```
n = 1000;    % number of samples
cutoff = 2;  % Cutoff point for min-value
mu = 4;      % Mean
p = .05;     % Percentile you would like to cutoff

z = -sqrt(2) * erfcinv(p*2);  % compute z score
sigma = (cutoff - mu)/z;      % compute standard deviation

A = normrnd(mu,sigma,[n 1]);
```

I would recommend removing values below the cutoff rather than re-attributing them to the lower bound of your distribution, but that is up to you.

```
A(A<cutoff) = []; % removes all values of A less than cutoff
```

If you want to be symmetrical (which you should to prevent sample skew) the following should work.

```
A(A>(2*mu-cutoff)) = [];
```